# Getting Access Id for Azure AD Access

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, adal, azure-ad-msal

I'm using adal.js to enable azure ad login via OAUTH.  I've started with this sample app, https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi

I need to be able to use Microsoft Graph Api in conjunction with this so that I can grab a list of the groups that the currently logged in user belongs to.  I don't know how to get the Access token to do this.  Note that I already have a good id_token.  Is there an additional redirection that I have to do after login?  Is this something that adal.js can help with?  Maybe msal.js?  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Edit 1:
I'm using the Azure AD version 1 endpoints.  I do not have the requirement that anyone outside of our AD needs to log in.  It's an enterprise app and should be limited to only my AD.  The users have more than 5 groups, thus the tokens have hasgroups:true instead of the actual groups list.  I need to call the graph api, but the id token that I'm issued doesn't work, I need an access token, which I don't know how to get.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you just need to use the right sample code:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-graphapi-v2

> A simple JavaScript single page application calling the MIcrosoft
>   Graph using msal.js (Azure AD V2 endpoint)

Comment: I've wandered in the wildness on this for a while.  I ran that sample, and I did get it to work, sort of...  I have to use another portal to register the app.  After registering the app, it seems that anyone with a microsoft account can log into the app.  This is bad, as this is an internal enterprise application.   I still stand by the original question, I'm using the 1.0 Azure AD endpoints to authorize a SPA app.  That works.  But the users are in too many groups, thus the requirement to use the Graph API to fetch the groups.  HELP!

Comment: If you followed the sample you linked, you should be getting an [access token](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi/blob/0a2f11dad9b705f9550f64198f0abfb1954bf36e/TodoSPA/App/Scripts/Ctrls/todoListCtrl.js). You have shared zero source code, zero authentication code, zero tokens, zero error messages. What do you want us to do to help?